# OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT in Viewer v7

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

`"Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT"` was working with viewer version 6, but when I upgrade viewer version to 7.*, its not working.

I have tried to handle `"Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT"`, and then call the `model.getObjectTree()` function, but I get the following error

> {instanceTree: null, maxTreeDepth: 0, err: undefined}

How can I handle the object_tree_created event for viewer 7 in my code?

Comment: Personally i use `viewer.model.getData().instanceTree` Can you try if that works for you ? Using the same event I haven't experienced issues in V7

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the model database (which contains object tree data) failed to load (and hence the object tree event was not fired and the object tree was not accessible) and it could have been for incorrect code or networking. Did you get other errors especially network interruptions in your browser's dev tools when loading the model? What is your code to load the model? If loading from Forge did you follow the [migration guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/) to use `loadDocumentNode`?

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'AutodeskProduction', getAccessToken}, () => {
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container);
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn, viewerDocument =>{
var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
```

Comment: Thnx Bryan, I have done the same thing now. I am loading a 2Dview in viewer, and I got all the 2D views from the revit file by using : 
var viewables = doc.getRoot().search({ type: "geometry", role: "2D"})
and then
viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, viewables[0]);
when I do this, I am getting error, 
"Uncaught TypeError: r.findPropertyDbPath is not a function"
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What is your `viewerDocument` here? It should be the `doc` object though

Comment: Yes, its doc object. Sorry for the typo

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `viewerables[0]` and also send the model over to look into? Simply upload to GDrive/Dropbox etc and drop the link to forge.help@autodesk.com? Tks!